# Cross compiling for Windows ARM on Linux x86-64

Tags: linux, windows, gcc, arm, cross-compiling

I want to compile some Windows applications for ARM on Linux x86-64. There are plenty of gcc-based cross compilers that generate ARM code on Linux x86-64, but they **don't include the required headers for Win32 development like Windows.h**. We also have mingw which I can use on Linux to build a Windows x86-64 binary. That's nice but Windows is also on ARM now. I want to be able to generate executables for ARM, not just x86-64. It seems like the only way to develop a Windows ARM application is to use Visual Studio on Windows.

Comment: If this is for professional purpose, I would respectfully strongly advise against it, because this is extremely unlikely you will be able to get any significant support from any source.What are the exact reasons you would want to do this ? Is this a matter of preferences ? of cost ? or something else ?

Comment: Have you ever heard of software like Linux, Java, Perl, Python, Ruby, Android, FreeBSD, Firefox, Chromium, gcc, mingw, Eclipse, JavaScript, bash, git, and docker? These are all open source products which are supported by the open source community. I don't think it is necessary to discuss whether this model of software development actually works since these products form the very basis of data centers and mobile software today. What I'm asking about is the same type of thing. The mingw cross compiler is already available in most Linux distros. I'm just asking about a new target architecture.

Comment: Any time someone develops something new, like a new programming language, there is no support for that new thing for the person who is developing it. They are on their own because they are the person creating it. The "no support" argument would prevent anyone from ever developing any new technology if it were a valid argument. Should Apple stop developing iPhones because there is no one besides themselves to pay for support for iPhones? Should Linus have never created Linux because there was no one he could pay to get support for Linux?

Comment: I am not saying this would not be a good thing. I would personally like this to be possible today.  I am just saying that, if this is not the case, what I think,  you would start developing your project with a beta quality software environment at best, and that this is not a good thing IMHO if your project has to deal with money and time constraints. This is a matter of facts. I did not say this was a crazy idea.

Comment: And no, I of course never heard of any of the  Linux, Java, Perl, Python, Ruby, Android, FreeBSD, Firefox, Chromium, gcc, mingw, Eclipse, JavaScript, bash, git, and docker you are mentioning.